# Add smooth effect on hiding a list

Tags: javascript, css, show-hide

I have a simple hide and show script for my list.
But Ideally i would like it to have a smooth effect on it.
Is there a way to make it similar to:

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#sortable

here is my JS:

```
function toggleA() {

    var list = document.getElementById("ListA");

    if (list.style.display == "none") {
    list.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        list.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a class and add an animation in the CSS.

Comment: can you please post full code in snippet?

Comment: Look at https://www.sitepoint.com/hide-elements-in-css/ It has notes whether some of the approaches could have smooth effect.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for effects you can use one of these

1. css animations (Really useful library: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)
2. slideUp using jquery (http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)
3. http://api.jquery.com/animate/  @Wesley Coetzee

And ofc you can make your own custom animations using css...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at jQuery animate?

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind using Jquery, as you've linked the example?

You can use [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) effect for that